# calculus notation on ordinary text editor

Tags: calculus

```
lim   1
x→0  --- = ∞
      x
-------------------------

5
∫ x^2dx= 
2
----------------------------
```

As I attempt to take notes on the calculus videos I'm watching, the above specimens are my efforts to write down what I'm seeing the professor write on his whiteboard.  It's very laborious since one equation can spread over three lines.  Is there a better way?  Either some editor that's prepped for math notation, OR, some protocol for writing a calculus equation on one line?  It's easy enough to include the special symbols of course.

For example, *and I'm making this up just to illustrate the point,*  supposing the second sample above might be written:

[5,2]∫ x^2dx=

... that is, I might not be the first guy to try to make some way of reducing a calculus equation to a single line in an ordinary text environment.  Has this been done?  What do folks do in my situation?

Comment: Well, something like Int[x^2,{x,2,5}] isn't bad.  And it works in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int%5Bx%5E2%2C%7Bx%2C2%2C5%7D%5D).

Comment: Cool.  So they have their own notation? That's just the sort of thing I had in mind.

Comment: Basically Mathematica notation.  Useful to learn, as you can just cut and paste the expression into the system to generate computations.

Comment: Sounds like exactly the thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not terribly worried about ease of reading (which, if you are, then I sincerely doubt there is a nice answer), then $\TeX$ formulas is one standard way of writing math formulas as pure text that most mathematicians know how to read. For instance,
$$
\int_2^5 x^2dx
$$
is written `\int_2^5 x^2dx`, and
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac1x = \infty
$$
is written `\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac1x = \infty`

Comment: Marvelous, that's a start.